# Jquery - disable button onsubmit and also change button name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i disable button on a webpage using ajax when clicked and also change the button name. I'm now converting my website to an app but it seems that same code doesn't work in jquery mobile.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();

        // Disable submit button on this specific form
        $('.btn-style1', this).val('Inserted').prop('disabled', true);

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "new_user.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {



            $("input[type=text]").val("");

        });
    });
});
```

any help?

Comment: How are you converting it to an app? What exactly does not work? When the code is called within a mobile device it is very probable that the page `new_user.asp` is not accessible from there. Try using the path to the website/url where that file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(this).find('.btn-style1').val('Inserted').prop('disabled', true);
```

try text instead of val if the text don't change

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/ua0dqo7k/1/

```
$("#change").click(function(){
    $("#test1").text("asdads");
    $("#test2").val("asdads");
    $("#test3").val("asdads");
});
```

Comment: nothing happens when i click, it disables but the text on the button doesn't change

Comment: I made a simple fiddle to illustrate what i was talking about. Input vs button react differently. Answer edited.